# Log4perl: separate INFO and ERROR files using easy_init

Tags: perl, log4perl

I am currently sending INFO and above to STDOUT using:

```
Log::Log4perl->easy_init({level=>("$INFO"), layout=>"%d %p - %m%n", file=>"STDOUT"});
```

How can I send ERROR and above to STDERR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is probably too much for easy_init setup, because you need to use filters to achieve that effect. With normal setup you can do this:

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->init(\ qq{
    log4perl.logger = INFO, AppInfo, AppError

    # Filter to match level ERROR
    log4perl.filter.MatchError = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
    log4perl.filter.MatchError.LevelToMatch  = ERROR
    log4perl.filter.MatchError.AcceptOnMatch = true

    # Filter to match level INFO
    log4perl.filter.MatchInfo  = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
    log4perl.filter.MatchInfo.LevelToMatch  = INFO
    log4perl.filter.MatchInfo.AcceptOnMatch = true

    # Error appender
    log4perl.appender.AppError = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
    log4perl.appender.AppError.stderr   = 1
    log4perl.appender.AppError.layout   = SimpleLayout
    log4perl.appender.AppError.Filter   = MatchError

    # Info appender
    log4perl.appender.AppInfo = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
    log4perl.appender.AppInfo.stderr   = 0
    log4perl.appender.AppInfo.layout   = SimpleLayout
    log4perl.appender.AppInfo.Filter   = MatchInfo
});

ERROR "Error";
INFO "Info";
```

Comment: Can i have a way such that when i write to error log then my script should exit immediately?